# Responsive image fluid

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi guys can you help on my problem, I want to make a fluid image (responsive) when browser scale even if the image is not hitting at the edge of the browser.

[image]

Comment: can't help without you showing your code

Comment: can you suggest any code about my problem?

Comment: can you suggest any code about my problem?

Comment: Please show us your html code

Comment: No I can't, It's would be a complete shot in the dark. Did you search Google or anywhere?

Comment: You'e not explained a problem, and you've shown no HTML we can help you troubleshoot. Please read [ask] and then come back to [edit] your question.

Comment: <html>
 <head>
 <title>Responsive image</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style='width:100%'>
   <div style='width:100px; height:100px'>
    <img src='img/image.jpg' style='width:100%; height:auto' />
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Responsive image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='width:100%'>
            <div style='width:100px; height:100px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto'>
                <img src='img/image.jpg' style='width:100%; height:100%' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Html:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7k96add9/

Comment: Thank you but that not what i mean for.

Comment: Well you need to tell us what you "mean for"